# Bash Curl Loop Repeation

Tags: bash, curl

I have this question, why my context in file is not being submit properly from bash script, I just want to post my context in file to server via my parameters.

Error: My complete directory listings get posted into server.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm cookiestore.txt
rm output.txt
echo -e ""
echo -e "[-] Input Setting      "
echo -ne "[+] Enter Host        : "
read Host
echo -e "[?] Obtaining Cookie       "
curl --silent --cookie-jar cookiestore.txt $Host > /dev/null
echo -ne "[+] Enter Parameters          : "
read Parameters
echo -ne "[+] Enter File Path       : "
read Filepath
echo -e ""
echo -e "[-] Performing Request         "
echo -ne "[?] Checking Response URL : "
curl -sI $Host -w '%{response_code}%{redirect_url}\n' -o /dev/null
echo -ne "[?] Final Redirected Url  : "
curl -Ls $Host -o /dev/null -w '%{url_effective}'
echo -e ""
echo -e ""
echo -e "[-] Posting    "
echo -e "[+] Output file            : output.txt"
echo -e ""
while read query
do
    content=$(curl -L -X POST $Host --data "{$Parameters${query}}")
    echo $query
    echo $content >> output.txt
done < query.txt
echo -e ""
echo -e "[-] Finished       "
echo -e ""
```

Comment: `"{$Parameters${query}}"` should be `"${Parameters}${query}"`

Comment: Use `set -x` to see the commands that are being executed with variables filled in.

Comment: That fixed it, I'm getting backslash \, in my few queries when it reads few stuff from my query file, is that normal in curl or error based query?

Comment: That's just the way `set -x` displays strings that contain special characters.

Comment: Just so you know, read has a `-p` option which prints a string: `read -p "Your name? " NAME`.